# TMX Map does not read Objects position properly when running retina?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, position, tmx

Currently working on a game, and is converting it to retina. I am using cocos2d and Tiled.
I have followed the guide on their site: [Retina Display in cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d#ccnode_details), but having problems with the position of objects.


What im doing right now:

```
NSMutableDictionary *playerSpawn = [objects objectNamed:@"SpawnPoint"];
NSAssert(playerSpawn != nil, @"Player spawn object not found");

int x = [[playerSpawn valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
int y = [[playerSpawn valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
self.player.position = ccp(x,y);
```

This sd TMX map is working just fine, but when running in Retina, the objects is not positioned correctly.

If i log the position it gives me:

```
// SD
158.000000, 63.000000

// Retina
158.000000, 383.000000
```

Ideas of what i could be doing wrong is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. 
I had to divide my retrived X an Y positions with `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()`
I also had to divide with `CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()`each time i used `tilemap.tileSize.height` and `tilemap.tileSize.width`.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar problems, could you describe more precisely what did you do to fix it? Using your example, no matter how hard I try to divide 383 by 2 (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() value on retina devices) it never equals 63. Nor is 158/2=158. So I assume there must be some additional steps you do to make this work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with this for a few hours, so I thought I'd share how I solved it :)

```
self.hero.position = [self ccpConvertForRetina:ccp(x, y) :self.map];

- (CGPoint) ccpConvertForRetina : (CGPoint) pointToConvert : (CCTMXTiledMap*) map {

    if (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2) {

        float x = pointToConvert.x;
        float y = pointToConvert.y;

        float numBortHeight = map.mapSize.height;
        float tileSizeHeight = map.tileSize.height;

        float yCalc = y - (tileSizeHeight*numBortHeight) / 2;

        return CGPointMake(x,yCalc);
    }
    else {
        return pointToConvert;
    }

}
```